# Could you let me know what does mean this "Need your hip waders to walk into a room"?

Tags: expressions

Could you let me know what does mean this "Need your hip waders to walk into a room" ?

Probably, someone talked a lot.  and room is full of after someone talks.

And could you show me some examples including this expression?

Comment: Where did you come across this expression? Google doesn't get any hits on it.

Comment: The phrase needs context and you should tell us, in the question,  where you found it.

Comment: Is "waders" a typo? Is it WANDERS?

Comment: @Mari-LouA "hip waders" are hip-high waterproof leggings, typically used by anglers.

Comment: The room could be full of any number of things you don't want to step in, literal or metaphorical. Macbeth used a metaphor of wading through blood, but he didn't have waders. But there is no way of knowing without the context.

Comment: Without context, we're just guessing. But my guess is it's a facetious reference to a ***funeral parlour*** or similar - where you'll need hip waders to withstand a flood of mourners' tears.

Answer (score 1):

#### The room is full of water

Hip waders are waterproof lower-body clothing that reach above the hips. They are often used by fishermen and others who need to walk into water but do not want to get wet.

[image]

If the remark is intended literally, the room is flooded with water, e.g. after a river has overflowed.

Alternatively, the remark is intended figuratively, and the room has many things scattered around the floor, or many people in it.